# remove log4j from grails

Tags: grails

I am using grails 2.1.1.  I would like to remove log4j completely as it is creating problems.  What is the best way to remove log4j from my grails application?  I would like to have no logging at the moment

Comment: Just because of interest: What kind of problems does log4j create?

Comment: My understanding is it creates log files, but doesn't work with 2.1 and over

Comment: From where did you get the information that it does not work with 2.1+? In the latest grails documentation (2.2.1) you find a chapter on configuring log4j (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging)